# JavaScript addEventListener() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have never used `addEventListener()`, but I cannot write the HTML equivalent I would like for each `<div>` I am treating as a button because of the way I am generating content. The equivalent would be:

```
<div onmousedown="jsItems[someId].toggleImage(someGallery, someIndex);"></div>
```

What I've been trying is this:

```
JsTree.prototype.addGalleries = function(inElements) {
    // ...unrelated code here removed for StackOverflow...

    for (var i = 0; i < this.jsGalleries.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length; j++) {
            var self = this;
            this.jsGalleries[i].buttons[j].addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
                self.toggleImage(i, j);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Where `i` counts from 0 to 1 and `j` counts from 0 to 2 (for both `i` in this case), `i` represents `someGallery`, `j` represents `someIndex`, and I could access `someId` with `this.id` inside the code above (or with `self.id` inside `addEventListener`'s function).

The problem is that although clicking on one of these "buttons" (`<div>`s) does trigger:

```
JsTree.prototype.toggleImage = function(inGallery, inIndex) {
    alert(this.id+", "+inGallery+", "+inIndex);
}
```

that it always alerts "8, 2, 3" regardless of which button is clicked. The "8" is correct but I have no idea why "2" or "3" are alerted. They seem to just be 1 more than what `i` and `j` count to (verified by trying `j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length-1` which alerts "8, 2, 2").

**Edit**: `someId`, `someGallery`, and `someIndex` are not real variables, they are junk I made up to try to explain the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic JS mistake. The problem is that the values of `i` and `j` are not captured in any function scope, and your event handlers are asynchronous. That means that when your event handler runs, both `for` loops have run to completion, thus `i == this.jsGalleries.length` and `j === this.jsGalleries[this.jsGalleries.length - 1].buttons.length`.

Try out one of these:

```
JsTree.prototype.addGalleries = function(inElements) {
  // ...unrelated code here removed for StackOverflow...

  for (var i = 0; i < this.jsGalleries.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length; j++) {
      (function(self, innerI, innerJ){
        var galleryEl = self.jsGalleries[innerI].buttons[innerJ];
        galleryEl.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
          self.toggleImage(innerI, innerJ);
        });
      })(this, i, j);
    }
  }
}
```

Or possibly clearer:

```
JsTree.prototype.addGalleries = function(inElements) {
  // ...unrelated code here removed for StackOverflow...

  var addHandler = function(self, i, j){
    self.jsGalleries[i].buttons[j].addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
      self.toggleImage(i, j);
    });
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < this.jsGalleries.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length; j++) {
      addHandler(this, i, j);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think the second one will be easier for me to understand

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem with addEventListener. This is a common mistake. In order to understand what's going on, I have to explain how closures work.

When you have a loop and a function inside of it:

```
var i = 5;
while(i--){
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(i);
  }, 100);
}
```

Each function is given a reference to the variable `i`. That means that they don't retain the value of `i` at the time you defined them. Again, I'll restate, each function has a reference to the same variable `i`, not to the value that it had at the time the function was declared. In my example above, all of the setTimeout's are defined asynchronously. The anonymous functions all fire at 100 milliseconds and each one logs the value that's in `i` at the time that the function was run. In my example, that value would be -1 for all the functions.

There are 2 ways to solve this. I'll show you the easy one first:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.jsGalleries.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length; j++) {
        var self = this;
        self.gallery = {i: i, j: j};
        this.jsGalleries[i].buttons[j].addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            self.toggleImage(self.gallery.i, self.gallery.j);
        });
    }
}
```

Here, you're storing the values on the actual DOM element. These values are equivalent to the values at the time that the loop was run, so the event listener grabs the correct value. Notice I nested the value in an object called gallery. I did this to kind of namespace it. It's not a good idea to store values on elements in the DOM, just in case browsers end up implementing a property with the same name. I feel like gallery is safe enough.

The other option, and probably the best practice, for fixing this is to use closures to your advantage.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.jsGalleries.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < this.jsGalleries[i].buttons.length; j++) {
        var self = this;
        this.jsGalleries[i].buttons[j].addEventListener("mousedown", (function closure(self, i, j){
            return function actualListener(){
                self.toggleImage(i, j);
            }
        })(self, i, j));
    }
}
```

In this case, we create a self executing function (called closure in my example) which runs immediately when we're creating the listener. Let me state it again, this function runs the moment the listener is being added, NOT when it's run. The reason we do this is so we can pass in the values we want to save for later, in this case, self, i, and j. Then, when the event occurs, the function that ACTUALLY gets run is the inner function (called actualListener). actualListener has a copy of all the values stored in its closure at the time that the closure function was run.

Comment: I understand the problem now, thank you. Still going to take a moment to understand the solution, I'll reread a few times, ha ha

Comment: I'm adding the other solution, which is probably the one you want to use. I'll break it down here in a sec ;-)

Comment: I don't understand `(self, i, j)` at the end of the function's `}`. Could you talk about that please?

Comment: `function(a,b){ console.log(a,b) }(1,2)` is the same as `function blah(a,b){ console.log(a,b) }; blah(1,2)`. In the second case, `blah` is equal to `function(a,b){ console.log(a,b) }`. Using parenthesis is what tells the interpreter to execute a command.

Comment: You don't have to surround the function with `()` but people do so as a common curtesy so that you know the function is immediately being invoked. `(function(){})(222)` is equal to `function(){}(222)`

Comment: Thank you for explaining, but to be honest I feel like I would have to practice that quite a lot for it to be something I'd use. I think I'd have a hard time even understanding it in the morning without reading your explanation again.

Comment: Agreed, not a simple concept. It's easier to understand with pictures on a whiteboard =P It's actually the exact same thing as @loganfsmyth's answer.